# Can we please get some of the new migration goodness?

Tags: feature-request, off-topic

To powers that be:

When should we expect to see the new migration options come in to play? There's a few questions I'd like to shuffle off to Server Fault or Stack Overflow

Comment: Looks like you got your wish!

Comment: Woohoo. Migrating here I come!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, I tried it out today.